# libwayland-egl.so is installed by both wayland and mali-t62x

Tags: yocto, bitbake, openembedded, wayland, odroid

I am trying to build image with **weston** for the **odroid xu4** device, but I am getting this errors:

```
ERROR: weston-4.0.0-r0 do_prepare_recipe_sysroot: The file /usr/lib/libwayland-egl.so is installed by both wayland and mali-t62x, aborting
ERROR: weston-4.0.0-r0 do_prepare_recipe_sysroot: Function failed: extend_recipe_sysroot
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/igor/Downloads/openembedded-core/build/tmp-glibc/work/cortexa15hf-neon-oe-linux-gnueabi/weston/4.0.0-r0/temp/log.do_prepare_recipe_sysroot.1623
ERROR: Task (/home/igor/Downloads/openembedded-core/meta/recipes-graphics/wayland/weston_4.0.0.bb:do_prepare_recipe_sysroot) failed with exit code '1'
ERROR: cogl-1.0-1.22.2-r0 do_prepare_recipe_sysroot: The file /usr/lib/libwayland-egl.so is installed by both wayland and mali-t62x, aborting
ERROR: cogl-1.0-1.22.2-r0 do_prepare_recipe_sysroot: Function failed: extend_recipe_sysroot
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/igor/Downloads/openembedded-core/build/tmp-glibc/work/cortexa15hf-neon-oe-linux-gnueabi/cogl-1.0/1.22.2-r0/temp/log.do_prepare_recipe_sysroot.1622
ERROR: Task (/home/igor/Downloads/openembedded-core/meta/recipes-graphics/cogl/cogl-1.0_1.22.2.bb:do_prepare_recipe_sysroot) failed with exit code '1'
ERROR: libepoxy-1.5.2-r0 do_prepare_recipe_sysroot: The file /usr/lib/libwayland-egl.so is installed by both wayland and mali-t62x, aborting
ERROR: libepoxy-1.5.2-r0 do_prepare_recipe_sysroot: Function failed: extend_recipe_sysroot
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/igor/Downloads/openembedded-core/build/tmp-glibc/work/cortexa15hf-neon-oe-linux-gnueabi/libepoxy/1.5.2-r0/temp/log.do_prepare_recipe_sysroot.1621
ERROR: Task (/home/igor/Downloads/openembedded-core/meta/recipes-graphics/l
```

Is it possible to resolve them somehow?

Comment: Maybe related: https://github.com/agherzan/meta-raspberrypi/issues/243

Comment: The first step is to figure out whether you actually need both 'wayland' and 'mali-t62x'. Since they both seem to provide the same file, my guess is "no", but I'm not really familiar with Wayland. The nuclear option (which is almost certainly wrong here) is to create a .bbappend targeting *one* of the recipes, with a `do_install_append` that deletes the file (from ${D}).